# Using a namespace only inside one specific class file

Tags: c++, using

This is a rather simple question more or less considering syntax semantics.

I've got a class inside a namespace, which uses a lot of classes out of another namespace:

```
namespace SomeNamespace
{
   class MyClass
   {
      //...

      //These types of namespace uses occur alot around here:
      void DoSomething(const anothernamespace::anotherclass &arg);
      //...
   }
}
```

This class is of course in its own .hpp file.

I would like to make everything inside the namespace "anothernamespace" available to the MyClass class, however, if I simply put it like this:

```
namespace SomeNamespace
{
   using namespace anothernamespace;
   class MyClass
   {
      //...

      //These types of namespace uses occur alot around here:
      void DoSomething(const anothernamespace::anotherclass &arg);
      //...
   }
}
```

Anyone who does

```
using namespace SomeNamespace;
```

Will automatically also use anothernamespace - which is what I want to avoid.

How do I achieve what I want?

Comment: "Doctor, doctor - it hurts when I do this!"

Comment: While not being the same, you could just `typedef anothernamespace::anotherclass anotherclass` all the types you need. You could *eek* even use a macro for that like `#define TYPE_IMPORT(namespace, class) typedef namespace::class class`.

Comment: @Bo Persson . Sorry, I don't understand. Is what I'm trying to do bad style? Otherwise I don't understand the relevancy of your comment.

Comment: Yes, what you are trying to do is bad style.  You are better off fully specifying anothernamespace:: on all of your types in the header.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does what you want.  Both namespaces are accessible to MyClass.  `using namespace` is bad practice in headers though.

```
namespace SomeNamespace {
namespace other {
  using namespace anothernamespace;
  class MyClass {
  };
}}

namespace SomeNamepace {
  typedef other::MyClass MyClass;
}
```

You really should prefer specifying anothernamespace:: in your class declaration.

Comment: This looks ugly, but I think it does what I want exactly, so I'm accepting it (I won't use it though - if there is no safe way of doing this without workarounds, I will simply use the :: operator a lot :) ).

Comment: I use similar techniques in detail namespaces a lot.  Then I `using namespace detail` inside of an anonymous namespace in a cpp file.  Inside of headers I don't think its a great practice, though rather harmless in this instance.  If you had to deal with porting someone else's mistakes I don't think I'd be angry ;)

Answer (score 6):

The simplest non-perfect-but-helping solution would be to use a namespace alias :

```
namespace SomeNamespace
{
   namespace ans = anothernamespace; // namespace alias
   class MyClass
   {
      //...

      //These types of namespace uses occur alot around here:
      void DoSomething(const ans::anotherclass &arg);
      //...
   }
}
```

Your class users will not "using namespace anothernamespace;", making it more safe, but you still have to use the alias in your class. Not sure it helps, it depends on if you just want to type less or maybe hide a type. Here you put the full namespace in a kind of sub-namespace that don't get into the user's namespaces, but is still available.

Otherwise... there is no way to do exactly what you want. Using namespace don't work inside class declarations.

Comment: Why not just put anothernamespace:: on everything?

Comment: Well sometimes, often when you don't have control on anothernamespace naming, it's just easier to setup a namespace alias. Real world example : boost::filesystem -> bfs or boost::msm::frontend/backend ->bmsmf . Abstractions are used to ease expression, having very long names that we have to use often makes writing them laborious, so any shortcut is good to know.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. It's just that simple, I'm afraid.